# Why is COUNT sometimes so slow in Google Cloud SQL?

Tags: mysql, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-sql

My DB is stored in Google Cloud SQL (MySQL). The table has approx. 11M rows.
Why is the simple select count so slow?

I'm using the following query:

```
select count(*) from my_table;
```

The response time is e.g:

- more than 2 minutes
- 29s
- 3s (was some cache used?)

Doesn't the DB have some simple counter for rows count? I guess that the count query should be calculated immediately.

Can I speed it up?

Note 1: I'd say that it was working fine a month ago but I'm not sure.

Note 2: Table size is 4GB, and machine is db-n1-standard-2 (2vCPU, 7.5 GB)

### Update Aug 14

COUNT is fast today. The worst time was 4s. Was the tomorrow lag caused by some Google Platform issue? Can I ssh to SQL machine directly to monitor its resources and swap file?

I tried Tommy's hints and there is another strange thing. Explain shows NULL for many table columns. Can it be cause by different server versions? My is `Server version: 5.7.14-google-log (Google)`

I used:

```
explain select count(1) from my_table;
```

The result is:

```
| id | select_type | table | partitions | type | possible_keys | key  | key_len | ref  | rows | filtered | Extra                        |
|  1 | SIMPLE      | NULL  | NULL       | NULL | NULL          | NULL | NULL    | NULL | NULL |     NULL | Select tables optimized away |
```

In JSON:

```
{
  "query_block": {
    "select_id": 1,
    "message": "Select tables optimized away"
  }
```

Comment: Did you follow Best Practices [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/mysql/best-practices#data-arch) provided by Google ?

Comment: Yes, I followed the documentation. Please see my update.

Comment: CloudSQL instances are google managed, so you are not able to ssh into them and perform actions of a SUPERUSER.

Answer (score 1):

By default, databases are generally optimized for a particular kind of usage pattern. So doing any extra work needlessly impacts performance negatively. Even keeping a *simple count* is not done because it can put a serious ding on how many things it can do per second.

Here's an experiment you can try (MySQL 5.7). First create a simple table with no indices.

```
create table A (
  B int
);

explain select count(1) from A;

id  select_type table   partitions  type    possible_keys   key key_len ref rows    filtered    Extra
1   SIMPLE  A   NULL    ALL NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    1   100.00  NULL
```

And as json:

```
{
    "data":
    [
        {
            "id": 1,
            "select_type": "SIMPLE",
            "table": "A",
            "partitions": null,
            "type": "ALL",
            "possible_keys": null,
            "key": null,
            "key_len": null,
            "ref": null,
            "rows": 1,
            "filtered": 100,
            "Extra": null
        }
    ]
}
```

The important part of the `Explain` output is the `"type": "ALL"` part, which says that to get the call, the database has to retrieve all the rows i.e. a table scan. This is why a select count is slow.

You can tell the database that a count is important to you by creating an index on a table. After every insert, the database has to update the indices for that table.

So let's add an index: `alter table A add index idx_A(B);`. And rerun the `explain` statement:

```
id  select_type table   partitions  type    possible_keys   key key_len ref rows    filtered    Extra
1   SIMPLE  A   NULL    index   NULL    idx_A   5   NULL    1   100.00  Using index
```

And again in json format:

```
{
    "data":
    [
        {
            "id": 1,
            "select_type": "SIMPLE",
            "table": "A",
            "partitions": null,
            "type": "index",
            "possible_keys": null,
            "key": "idx_A",
            "key_len": "5",
            "ref": null,
            "rows": 1,
            "filtered": 100,
            "Extra": "Using index"
        }
    ]
}
```

This time, notice the `type`, it is `index` and there's a key that it can use. The index will allow the query evaluator to return a count much more quickly.